# Python controle Constrain to Image Bounds

Tags: python, scripting, uv-image-editor

is it possible to controle True/False checkbox from **"UV/Image Editor > UVs > Constrain to Image Bounds"** via Python Console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look in info area**

In this case if we open an info window and toggle the setting in the image editor

[image]

We see the property is [`lock_bounds`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.SpaceUVEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceUVEditor.lock_bounds) of the [`uv_editor`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.html#bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.uv_editor) settings of the image editor space.
Python console code to get there, in same screen. *Beware: currently trying to auto complete an image editor  space from another (other than context) screen core dumps my 2.8 build*

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'OUTLINER')
(3, 'VIEW_3D')
(4, 'IMAGE_EDITOR')
(5, 'INFO')

>>> a  = C.screen.areas[4]
>>> s = a.spaces.active
>>> s
bpy.data.screens['Scripting.001']...SpaceImageEditor

>>> s.uv_editor.lock_bounds = True
>>>
```

Although can set without, for the menu to show, mesh object needs a UV map and be in edit mode.

Comment: thank you batFINGER <3